# How do you declare generic type of any "interface" in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

Given the following example code

```java
package com.test;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public interface TestA {}
    public interface TestB {}

    public static class Aclass implements TestA {}
    public static class Bclass implements TestA, TestB {}

    public static <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> getClassesThatImplement(Class<T> interfaceClass) {
        Reflections reflect = new Reflections("com.test");
        return reflect.getSubTypesOf(interfaceClass);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Class<? extends TestA>> aClasses = getClassesThatImplement( TestA.class );
        // Prints [class com.test.Main$Aclass, class com.test.Main$Bclass]
        System.out.println(aClasses);

        Set<Class<? extends TestB>> bClasses = getClassesThatImplement( TestB.class );
        // Prints [class com.test.Main$Bclass]
        System.out.println(bClasses);
    }
}
```

how can I limit my method, `getClassesThatImplement` to *only* accept interfaces so that I get compile time errors instead of runtime errors if I use a regular class? There is no common, or "root", interface I can use to "bound" my generic type `<T implements ...>`. Is there even a way to do that in Java or will I have to rely on runtime checks?

Comment: There is no way to do that; generics let you pick type bounds, but the notion of 'is an interface' vs 'is a class' isn't part of the java type system.

Comment: @user16320675 Then every class that implements such an interface would implement that as well. Which makes that rather pointless.